# Is there a better way to use pop so that we dont have to create a dictionary and pop out the items

Tags: python

```
pokemon = {

 "retro":"rayquaza",
 "chrome":"zekrom",
  "dark":"zygarde",
 "dark":"mewtwo",
 "mettalic":"dialga",
 "normal":"giratina",
 "light":"vitini",
 "sprite":"reshiram",
 "shiny":"pikachu",
 "shiny":"deoyxs",
}

x = pokemon.popitem()

print("Congratulations you recieved a :",x)
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you're currently doing?

Comment: Side note: you have duplicate keys in your dictionary, only one will be preserved if you check your dictionary after that assignment

Comment: If your goal is to just randomly pick a Pokemon without removing the key, you can use `random.sample` to randomly select a key and then if you have multiple values within that key you could do another `random.sample`.

Comment: I do not really understand what you are asking.

Comment: It would greatly help if you provide some information of what you are actually trying to do. Right now, you will always get `("shiny", "deoyxs")` so the whole dict is useless...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be asking the wrong question. It's often helpful to share what your goal is.

Since you mention not wanting to use a dictionary, it sounds like the items are the only thing you care about. If this is the case, you can alternatively store your Pokemon names in a list and use the `.pop()` method.

```
pokemon = ['Rayquaza', 'Zekrom', 'Mewtwo']
x = pokemon.pop()
print(f"Congratulations! You received a {x}!")
```

If you want a random Pokemon from the list, you can import 'random' and use the `random.shuffle()` method on your list prior to popping out an item.

```
import random

pokemon = ['Rayquaza', 'Zekrom', 'Mewtwo']
random.shuffle(pokemon)
x = pokemon.pop()
print(f"Congratulations! You received a {x}!")
```